# UUID in /etc/mtab

Tags: linux, mount, fstab, proc

In some versions of Ubuntu. Disks are mounted by UUID. in My machine, `/proc/mounts`

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/UUID / ext4 rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,barrier=1,data=ordered 0 0
```

`/etc/fstab`

```
UUID=U-U-I-D  /   ext4  errors=remount-ro        0  1
```

But in `/etc/mtab`

```
/dev/sda1 / ext4 rw,errors=remount-ro,commit=0 0 0
```

So is it guaranteed that there will be no UUID in `/etc/mtab` ?

Answer (score 1):

This is not guaranteed in general. On Ubuntu, I think it's always true in typical situations, but there may be corner cases lurking. Specifically, to generate `/etc/mtab`, the `mount` program runs some [code](https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/utils/util-linux/util-linux/+/stable/v2.20/lib/fsprobe.c) (the function `fsprobe_get_devname_by_spec`) to convert a specification such as `UUID=…` or `LABEL=…` into a device path such as `/dev/sdz99`. This is not done if you pass the `--no-canonicalize` option to `mount`.

There are systems where `/etc/mtab` is a symbolic link to `/proc/mounts`. This is useful where the root filesystem is mounted read-only.

Answer (score 0):

mtab is what the mount command reads from to show currently mounted filesystems, I dont think it ever shows UUIDs.